# No Such Table Fatal Exception: SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am beginner in Android. I am making a database through SQLite. I created the Arabic database file and put it in assets folder with the name `sample.db`. Now I am trying to read the database from the assets folder but I'm getting an error and app is crushing. What's the best way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

this is the code in DbHelper.java

```
package ...
import ...

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    String dbName;
    Context context;
    String dbPath;

    String tableName = "Dictionary";
    String ArabicCol = "Arabic";

    public DbHelper(MainActivity mcontext, String name, int version) {
        super(mcontext, name, null, version);


        this.context = mcontext;
        this.dbName = name;
        this.dbPath = "/data/data" + "com.example.e_qtishaddictionary3" + "databases";
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if(newVersion>oldVersion)
            CopyDatabase();
    }
    public void CheckDb(){
    SQLiteDatabase CheckDb =  null;
            try {
                String filePath = dbPath + dbName;

                CheckDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(filePath, null, 0);
            }catch (Exception e) {
            }

            if (CheckDb != null) {
                Log.d("CheckDb", "Database already exists");
                CheckDb.close();
            } else {
                CopyDatabase();
            }
        }
        public void CopyDatabase() {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try{
                InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(dbName);
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbPath + dbName);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int len;
                while((len = is.read(buffer))>0){
                    os.write(buffer,0,len);
                }
                os.flush();
                is.close();
                os.close();
            }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            Log.d("CopyDb", "Database Copied");
        }
        public void OpenDatabase(){
            String filepath = dbPath + dbName;
            SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(filepath,null,0);
        }
        public ArrayList<String> getArabicWord(String query){
        ArrayList<String> arabicList = new ArrayList<>();

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor;
            cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(
                    tableName,
                    new String[]{ArabicCol},
                    ArabicCol + " LIKE ? ",
                    new String[]{query + "%"},
                    null, null,
                    ArabicCol
            );
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(ArabicCol);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                arabicList.add(cursor.getString(index));
            }

            sqLiteDatabase.close();
            cursor.close();
            return arabicList;
        }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package ...
import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;
    DbHelper dbHelper;

    ArrayList<String> newList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        autoCompleteTextView = findViewById(R.id.autotxt);
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(this,"sample.db",1);
        try{
           dbHelper.CheckDb();
           dbHelper.OpenDatabase();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        newList = new ArrayList<>();

        autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if(s.length() > 0 ){
                    newList.addAll(dbHelper.getArabicWord(s.toString()));

                    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newList));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

this is part of my logcat

```
(1) no such table: Dictionary in "SELECT Arabic FROM Dictionary WHERE Arabic LIKE ?  ORDER BY Arabic"
2023-04-20 03:27:40.261 17406-17406 AndroidRuntime          com.example.e_qtishaddictionary3     D  Shutting down VM
2023-04-20 03:27:40.264 17406-17406 AndroidRuntime          com.example.e_qtishaddictionary3     E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.e_qtishaddictionary3, PID: 17406
                                                                                                    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Dictionary (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT Arabic FROM Dictionary WHERE Arabic LIKE ?  ORDER BY Arabic
                                                                                                        at
```

and the line concerned

```
at com.example.e_qtishaddictionary3.DbHelper.getArabicWord(DbHelper.java:84)
                                                                                                        at com.example.e_qtishaddictionary3.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:44)
```

I've read my code 2 days, but I can't figure out where I'm wrong. Can you help me? Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fix the URL of database

```
this.dbPath = "/data/data" + "com.example.e_qtishaddictionary3" + "databases";
```

to be like below

```
this.dbPath = "/data/data/" + "com.example.e_qtishaddictionary3/" + "databases/"
```

Second, you forgot to add the command to create the table itself first **Dictionary** so you need to add on the **void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)**  the below creation sql command for the table

```
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " ("
            + ArabicCol +" TEXT not null);");
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, sorry for taking so long to reply because I just started my activities after a long weekend. but I'm so sorry your answer didn't help, because still error occurs with the same logcat :(

Answer (score 0):

Before finding out where the problem is, one mistake you have done. Pls correct it.

The path of the database folder is wrong.

```
this.dbPath = "/data/data" + "com.example.e_qtishaddictionary3" + "databases";
```

should be changed to

```
this.dbPath = "/data/data/" + "com.example.e_qtishaddictionary3" + "/databases";
```

And I am assuming that you have the file 'sample.db' in your resources/assets. Can you cross check if you have it?